# Hide mobile hotspot ssid on windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, hotspot

My windows 10 laptop is connected to an ethernet connection i am using mobile hotspot on windows to get a connection for my phone. My problem that I don't want this ssid to be noticed is there any way to do that

Answer (score -2):

I'm not aware of a way to do that; it doesn't seem to be implemented.

What you could do, however, is to make an SSID like HP_Printer or something like that, so people think it's something else.